# Mitigate connection between two wireless access points

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I was wondering if there was a way to connect a single computer to two different access points.  I'm on a network with a lot of users and the usage gets bogged down.  Using two wireless antennas can I connect to two different points and share the load between them?  Is there software to do this, if it is even possible?  Or would I be able to run two different programs off of the different antennas? Say two instances of Firefox, or Firefox and Steam.

Using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WiFi NIC can only support being connected to 1 access point (as far as I know), irregardless of how many antennas it has connected to it. So you'd need multiple WiFi NICs.

If you did have multiple NICs then you could take a look at this U&L Q&A titled: [Using multiple NICs for faster internet?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81197/using-multiple-nics-for-faster-internet), for what options you have in terms of using them simultaneously.

Comment: So according to this I can bond my ethernet and wifi?  Since those are two different controllers

Comment: @StevenWalton - That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You would need two wireless interfaces to do this, it's the hardware of the wireless card that's important, not the antennas themselves.

Comment: I have an internal antenna and an external antenna.

Comment: Do you have multiple NICs?

Comment: I have a Network Controller and an Ethernet Controller.  Could I join those two?